# How to open a banch of files in a text editor from shell?

Tags: linux, editor

Assuming I work under linux, how do I open a directory of files (contains `.c` ,`.h` ,`.cpp`) using `emacs`, `vim`, `vi` or `gedit`?

I mean like open all the directory from the shell and have the list of the files in the right/left side?

Comment: You question is not clear , open directories ? You just want to navigate to the directory ?
You can't open a "directory" using VIM ( you can but not much use ) . You can open files. find ./ -name "*.c" Lists all the .c files in the current directory and its sub direcrtory for example .

Comment: Opening a directory in Vim is quite useful. You can descend into directories, go up into others, rename files, select files for editing, and more.

Comment: Anyone else find it odd the OP doesn't mind if it's vi or emacs? o_O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to open it in vim-

```
vim *.c *.h *.cpp
```

and then use :next and :prev to navigate between all open files

Comment: For the lazy, `:n` will do the trick (commands are `:n[exit]` and `prev[ious]`).

Comment: (Just to be clear, my typo there was supposed to be `n[ext]`).

Answer (score 2):

You probably mean something like NERDTree for vi (there are also other plugins for emacs etc.).

Check out this page for screenshots: [NERDTree for VI](http://www.flickr.com/photos/rodneybohner/2862367534/sizes/m/)

Answer (score 2):

This will open Emacs in `dired` mode in the current directory.

```
emacs .
```

This will open one buffer for each file in the current directory.  Presumably you can do the same with e*vi*l.

```
emacs *
```